# Angular freeze the website after some animations

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a website in angular where I have an effect that show and hide the photos in the home https://es.design/
After some times that the effect go the website page of chrome crash and the website freeze. Maybe the problem is that the website load every time again the photos. How can we fix this in Angular?

```
  <div class="left">
    <div class="first">
      <div #firstBox style="background-image: url(../../../assets/color/{{firstRandomPhoto}}.jpeg)" [style.top.%]="firstPosition" class="photo-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <div #secondBox style="background-image: url(../../../assets/color/{{secondRandomPhoto}}.jpeg)" [style.top.%]="secondPosition" class="photo-box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
// Effetto foto
  firstRandomWidth: number = 0;
  secondRandomWidth: number = 0;

  firstRandomHeight: number = 0;
  secondRandomHeight: number = 0;

  firstPosition: number = 0;
  secondPosition: number = 0;

  firstRandomPhoto:number = 0;
  secondRandomPhoto:number = 0;

  firstLeft:number = 0;
  secondLeft:number = 0;

  @ViewChild('firstBox') firstBox!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('secondBox') secondBox!: ElementRef;

  photoEffect() {
    this.firstRandomWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 181) + 250;
    this.secondRandomWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 181) + 250;

    this.firstRandomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 181) + 250;
    this.secondRandomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 181) + 250;

    this.firstLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 20;
    this.secondLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 20;

    this.firstPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 10;

    while (true) {
      this.secondPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 10;
      if (this.secondPosition !== this.firstPosition &&
          Math.abs((this.secondRandomHeight / 100) - Math.floor(this.secondPosition / 10)) > 0.5 &&
          Math.abs(this.secondPosition - this.firstPosition) >= 15) {
        break;
      }
    }

    this.firstRandomPhoto = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 1;

    while (true) {
      this.secondRandomPhoto = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 1;
      if (this.secondRandomPhoto !== this.firstRandomPhoto) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (this.firstBox && this.secondBox) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.firstBox.nativeElement, 'width', this.firstRandomWidth+"px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.firstBox.nativeElement, 'height', this.firstRandomHeight+"px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.firstBox.nativeElement, 'top', this.firstPosition+"px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.firstBox.nativeElement, 'left', this.firstLeft + "px");

      this.renderer.setStyle(this.secondBox.nativeElement, 'width', this.secondRandomWidth+"px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.secondBox.nativeElement, 'height', this.secondRandomHeight+"px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.secondBox.nativeElement, 'top', this.secondPosition+"px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.firstBox.nativeElement, 'left', this.secondLeft + "px");
    }
  }
```

How can we stop that the pages freeze and crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the issue seams to be your loop runing in infinite loops with conditions that break them.

I would create count for while something like

```
let attempts = 0;
const maxAttempts = 1000;

while (attempts < maxAttempts) {
  this.secondPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 10;
  if (this.secondPosition !== this.firstPosition &&
      Math.abs((this.secondRandomHeight / 100) - Math.floor(this.secondPosition / 10)) > 0.5 &&
      Math.abs(this.secondPosition - this.firstPosition) >= 15) {
    break;
  }
  attempts++;
}

attempts = 0;
while (attempts < maxAttempts) {
  this.secondRandomPhoto = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 1;
  if (this.secondRandomPhoto !== this.firstRandomPhoto) {
    break;
  }
  attempts++;
}
```

or try to use for loop

```
  const maxAttempts = 1000;
    
    for (let attempts = 0; attempts < maxAttempts; attempts++) {
      this.secondPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 10;
      if (this.secondPosition !== this.firstPosition &&
          Math.abs((this.secondRandomHeight / 100) - Math.floor(this.secondPosition / 10)) > 0.5 &&
          Math.abs(this.secondPosition - this.firstPosition) >= 15) {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    for (let attempts = 0; attempts < maxAttempts; attempts++) {
      this.secondRandomPhoto = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 1;
      if (this.secondRandomPhoto !== this.firstRandomPhoto) {
        break;
      }
    }
```

Btw: I would consider to work with lazy loading - load images only when they're needed.

Comment: I edited the code but continue freeze, all the images size are less than 2mb in total (more than 70). I don't really know